# Filtering null values in columns dynamically using functions

Tags: r, function, null, dplyr

I am trying to dynamically filter out null values from a column in my data frame. For this I need to pass the column name as a function parameter and then remove nulls. I have tried the following code and it gives me an error stating *"Warning message:In is.na(tableMQproblem$test) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'"* :-

```
library(dplyr)
tabledata  <- read.csv("data.csv",head=TRUE,sep= ',',check.names=FALSE)
tabledata[tabledata == ""] <- NA
x<-function(test)
{    
    tabledata  <- tabledata[!(is.na(tabledata$`test`)), ]
}

table_finalC <- x("confi Itm")
```

My Test data -

```
structure(list(R_co = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c(" ", 
"A220", "B334"), class = "factor"), confi_Itm = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "CFMX1"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("R_co", 
"confi_Itm"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to remove nulls from confi_Itm first and the output should be -:

```
R_co confi_Itm
1 A220     CFMX1
```

PS - tabledata  <- tabledata[!(is.na(tableMQproblem$`test`)), ] -- here test is enclosed in backticks because my column names have spaces. I was unable to make test data with column name having spaces(I have used underscore instead) but the real data has that in my case.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowSums` of the blank elements `''`, get a logical index for those rows with '0' blanks, and subset the dataset.

```
res <- droplevels(df[!rowSums(df==''),])
res
# R_co confi_Itm
#1 A220     CFMX1
```

We wrap it with `droplevels` (as the columns are `factor` class) to remove the unused `levels`.

Comment: Thanks akrun ,actually I need to filter out null values on a particular columnn one by one by passing the column as a parameter to the function. So I first pass confi_item and get an output where dataset.confi_item ne NULL. Then I pass R_co and get an output where dataset.R_co ne NULL.  I have many more columns and rowSums would consider them all so even if any of the other columns has NULL it will affect my output which will then be incorrect.